# Is there a way to remove redundant curly braces of C code?

Tags: c, python-3.x, parsing, logic, braces

I am working on parsing and regeneration of code. My grammar converts `else if` to `else { if` and automatically adds `{` and `}` for the body of `else if`. So a sample output code looks like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int choice = 1;
    switch (choice) {
    case 0:
        if (choice == 0) { {
                int option = 10;
                if (option < 11) { {
                        if (option < 10) { {
                                int temp;
                        }} else {
                            if (option == 10) { {
                                    int temp1;
                            }} else {
                                if (option ==
                                    90) { {
                                        int temp2;
                                }}
                }}}} else {
                    if (option == 20) { {
                            int temp3;
                    }}
        }}}
        break;
    case 1:
        if (choice == 1) { {
                int temp4;
        }}
        break;
    default:{ {
                int temp5;
        }} break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**How do I remove redundant flower braces from this code such that the logic remains the same? Is there some tool to do this, or some python code?**

I have tried writing python code to achieve this but am finding it hard to remove the correct number of extra closing flower braces `}` such that the logic of the C code remains unaffected.

Comment: This is not a trivial thing to do. It's likely that you would need a complete C parser to do it correctly. If I wanted to do this, I'd use the code from an existing parser to generate a tree. When this is done, it's fairly simple to remove the braces.

Comment: You need a parser, but if the goal is only to deal with redundant braces, the parser could be rather simple. In my opinion, no need to generate a tree.

Comment: It seems in this case you can repeatedly replace `{ {` with `{`. And `}}`with `}`

Comment: `flower braces` never heard them called that! I love it! (I usually call them `curly braces`.)

Comment: Is there a reason this question is tagged for python?